# Is It Possible To Have A JBoss standalone xml Hierarchy?

Tags: jboss

I am working on a standalone JBoss instance provided by a third party and I have made some customisations to the standalone xml for our purposes.
e.g. the login module

However, third party sends patches each month for different parts of the system which sometimes includes changes to the standalone xml.

Is it possible to have 2 standalone xml files - one from the third party and another with my customisations?
Or do I always have to diff and merge every time a patch comes in?

Comment: There is no way to do that. Do they send you the full file or just snippets? You might be able to convert them into CLI commands.

Comment: They send a full file. Are you suggesting that I could take the full file then add my parts using the CLI instead of a patch file?

Comment: Actually yes you could do that for sure. In fact I'd suggest it :) The XML file is really just a serialized version of the management model. It's best to make any management changes via some management helper like CLI or the web console.